# Proving a set is open iff its complement is closed from scratch

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We have that a set $F$ is closed if every limit point of $F$ is a point of $F$ and we say that $p$ is a limit point of a set $E$ is every neighborhood $N$ of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$. In other words, if $N \cap E \neq \varnothing$.

${\bf TASK:}$ Prove that $U$ is open iff $U^c$ is closed.

TRY: Let $U$ be a open set. Let $x$ be a limit point of $U^c$. We need to show that $x \in U^c$. If $x \in U$, then there is a neighboorhood $N$ of $U$ such that $N \cap U = \varnothing$ so that $x$ is not limit point. Therefore, $x$ better be in $U^c$, as desired.

On the other hand, say $U^c$ is closed. Let $x \in U$. We must find a neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $U$.

If we can show that $x$ is not  limit point of $U^c$, then we will be able to have a neightborhood $N$ that is completely outside $U^c$ (that is, inside of $U$). So if $x$ is a limit point of $U^c$, then $x \in U^c$ by assumption and this contradiction proves that $x$ is not a limit point of $U^c$.

Is this a correct proof?

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo.  You want to say $N \cap U^c = \emptyset$, not $N \cap U$.  I think your last paragraph has the right idea, but the way you've written it leaves it unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Typically a topology on a space $X$ is defined as a collection $\tau$ of subsets which contains $\emptyset$ and $X$, so that a finite intersection or arbitrary union of sets in $\tau$ is again in $\tau$, and the elements of $\tau$ are called the "*open sets*". The "*closed sets*" are then defined to be the complements of the open sets. This problem seems to be true *by definition*, unless you are starting from a very different definition of a topological space than the canonical one.

Comment: You define "closed" in your question.  That's good.  But you should also define "open" in your question. @RiversMcForge  The OP made it very clear in the very first sentence that he is using the metric space definition of "open" and "closed"  This fine.  But it is *essential* to prove immediately that metric space definitions obey the laws of topology.  Hence the OPs question.

Comment: "If we can show that x is not limit point of Uc, then we will be able to have a neightborhood N that is completely outside Uc "  That's a little breezy.  Put a bit more detail.  Also we don't (and can't) show the $x$ is not a limit point of $U^c$; we know because $x \not \in U^c$ and $U^c$ is close we *know* it isn't.  So not every neighborhood intersects $U^c$ so there is one that has no other point of $U^c$ other than $x$. And as $x$ *isn't* in $U^c$ no point in the neighborhood is. So the neighborhood contained in $U$.  So $x$ in interior point.

Comment: But otherwise you proof is quite good.  But a bit breezy but good.  And correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all $p$ is a limit point of $E$ iff for every neighbourhood $N$ of $p$ intersects $E\setminus\{p\}$. More succinct.

If $U$ is open, let $x$ be a limit point of $U^\complement$. If $x \in U$ there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subseteq U$ which implies that $N \cap U^\complement = \emptyset$ which a fortiori would imply that $X$ would *not* be a limit point of $U^\complement$, contradiction. So $x \in U^\complement$ and so $U^\complement$ is closed. ($N \cap U = \emptyset$ in your proof is a mistake!)

Suppose $U^\complement$ is closed. Let $x \in U$. Then $x$ cannot be a limit point of $U^\complement$ (or it would have been in $U^\complement$ by closedness), so there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $$N \cap (U^\complement\setminus\{x\}) = \emptyset = (N\setminus \{x\}) \cap U^\complement \tag{1}$$ Then $N \subseteq U$ follows. (let $y \in N$; if $y=x$ we are done right away as $x \in U$; otherwise $y \in N\setminus \{x\}$ so $y$ cannot also be in $U^\complement$, or it would contradict the empty intersection in $(1)$; in either case $y \in U$) and so all points of $x \in U$ are interior to $U$, so $U$ is open.

QED. This makes the argument stand out more, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your last paragraph isn't quite correct.

By assumption, $U^c$ is closed, so if $x \in U$, then because $U^c$ contains all of its limit points and $x \notin U^c$, we have that $x$ is not a limit point of $U^c$.  That means there is some neighborhood $N$ of $x$ that is disjoint from $U^c$, and a neighborhood that is disjoint from $U^c$ is necessarily contained within $U$.  Thus, $N$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained within $U$, and since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $U$, that means that $U$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to say is that $p$ is a limit point of $E$ when for every neighborhood $N$ of $p$, we have $N\cap E\setminus\{p\}\ne\emptyset$.

Everything works out, as this is usually taken as the definition.